# How does sweeping out equal areas in equal times show that the orbit is not a circle?

Tags: orbital-motion, history

In many popular accounts, Kepler is said to have discovered that the planets move in an ellipse and not a circle after discovering that the planets sweep out equal areas in equal times. For example, a [NASA page](https://earthobservatory.nasa.gov/features/OrbitsHistory/page2.php):

> Kepler noticed that an imaginary line drawn from a planet to the Sun swept out an equal area of space in equal times, regardless of where the planet was in its orbit. If you draw a triangle out from the Sun to a planet’s position at one point in time and its position at a fixed time later—say, 5 hours, or 2 days—the area of that triangle is always the same, anywhere in the orbit. For all these triangles to have the same area, the planet must move more quickly when it is near the Sun, but more slowly when it is farthest from the Sun.

> This discovery (which became Kepler’s second law of orbital motion) led to the realization of what became Kepler’s first law: that the planets move in an ellipse (a squashed circle) with the Sun at one focus point, offset from the center.

But doesn't a planet moving in a circle also sweep out equal areas in equal times?

How does sweeping out equal areas in equal times show that the orbit is not a circle?

Comment: *But doesn't a planet moving in a circle also sweep out equal areas in equal times?* Yes. *How does sweeping out equal areas in equal times show that the orbit is not a circle?* It doesn’t.

Comment: The velocity is constant along a circular orbit, the premise is wrong, it also covers same area in equal times. A circle is a special kind of ellipse, all Kepler laws also apply to circular orbits.

Answer (score 2):

Kepler did not derive his laws using mathematical calculations, but based on the astronomical observations that Brahe had collected in his lifetime and passed on to Kepler after his death.
Kepler's first law is not a **proof** of his second law, but a logical inference from it.

"Equal areas in equal times" means that the rate of change of the area swept out by the planet on its orbit ($\frac{dA}{dt}$) is constant (Angular momentum is conserved).
According to the first law, the orbit is an ellipse, so the planet moves faster when it is closer to the Sun, and slower when it is farther from the Sun. If the orbit were a circle, the planet would move at a constant speed.

The data showed that the speed of the planet changed over time, which implied that the distance between the planet and the Sun also changed. This way, the planet traced an elliptical orbit.

In summary,

Kepler's first law follows from his second law by noticing that for a planet to sweep out equal areas in equal times, its orbit must be an ellipse with the Sun at one of the foci. The second law also explains why the planet's speed varies in its orbit, resulting in an ellipse rather than a circle. The fact that these equal areas are preserved throughout the orbit confirms that the planets move in elliptical orbits around the Sun."

Comment: "Historically, the law of conservation of angular momentum was stated entirely in terms of [areal velocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Areal_velocity)".

Comment: @PM2Ring if you intend to criticize "Kepler did not derive his laws using mathematical calculations" . Argument from my side would be that, kepler's work was not much rigorous mathematically but rather more of intuitive data analysis, while what you state is a fact but areal velocity is perhaps high school physics thing. Please correct me if I have wrong presumptions..

Comment: I didn't intend to criticise anything in your answer. I was just adding related information. However, I will mention that Kepler was an excellent mathematician (or geometer, as they'd say in those days). Figuring out that orbits are ellipses, and Kepler's equation relating the eccentric & mean anomalies, was no mean feat, especially considering that he did it before the development of calculus.

Answer (score -3):

You must look at it from the point of view of the time. First of all, you have to connect the assumption of circular orbits to observational data, thereby deducing that, along the circular orbits, sometimes the orbits go fast, and sometimes the orbits go slow. Of course, you started out by assuming that they were moving at constant speeds, before better data showed that they are going fast and slow.

Kepler deduced backwards that the fast and slow can be explained by equal areas, and then that forces the trajectory to be ellipses.

Comment: No, the velocity is constant along a circular orbit, the OP premise is wrong. A circle is a special kind of ellipse, all Kepler laws also apply to circular orbits.

Comment: at the time, it was already known that there would be a need for epicycles. It wasn't a uniform speed circular orbit.

Comment: Equal area per unit time is the same as angular momentum conservation, so I think the point is that ellipses conserve angular momentum, so while a circle is an ellipse, an ellipse is sufficient to satisfy Kepler's law, and the knew circles were insufficient at the time. They key to this is the hidden $SO(4)$ symmetry that makes the energy independentl of the eccentricity--but that's a hole nother story.